# Analyze Twitter friends without exceeding rate limit

Tags: python-3.x, twitter, tweepy

How can I analyze a list of followers (or following), and count the number users with a following/follwer ratio of < .2 without it taking forever with the API limits?

This is the code I'm using to try to achieve this...

'''

```
friends = api.friends_ids(SCREEN_NAME)

count = 0

for friend in friends:
    if api.get_user(id=friend).friends_count / 
       api.get_user(id=friend).followers_count < .2:
           count += 1

print(count)
```

'''

I'm trying to figure out what percentage of users in the list have a ratio of 5-1 followers to following or better. Seems like it should be an easy task, but I can't get past the API limits.

Any help/advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I used this, and it works with no limit issues up to 3000...

```
friends = []
for friend in tweepy.Cursor(api.friends, count=200).items():
    friends.append(friend)
```